# TURNS / TURN protocol on Safari in iOS

Tags: safari, webrtc, turn, coturn

I am currently testing different TURN solutions on phones and noticed that the encrypted TURNs does not work on Safari.

When I define a single TURN server with:

`turn:my-turn.com:443`

it works without any problems. If I define a single TURN server with:

`turns:my-turn.com:443`

I can't make a connection with my iPhone on Safari (iOS 13.5.1) with LTE/3G, where TURN server is necessary. I want my customers to use always the encrypted protocol but will now have to add an unencrypted version to the servers too. Does anyone know the reason for this behavour or how I can make Safari make use the encrypted TURNS protocol? I am using CoTurn on the TURN server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're aware that webrtc is encrypted so using turns: only adds another of transport encryption to that? Also turns is running over TCP which has disadvantages for realtime media.

Comment: Apparently Safari has issues with LetsEncrypt certificates for turns. See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=11710